# Why is a firm, inflated stand up paddle board at atmospheric?

Tags: pressure, everyday-life

I have a new inflatable stand-up paddle board, which is supposed to be inflated to 15 psi. I had to pump a long time and it became very rigid—and when I opened the valve it let out a lot of air. I wondered what the pressure was in atmospheric pressures, and was surprised to see that 15 psi is very close to 1 atm (1.02069 atm).

I'm at a complete loss to understand how something that is evidently under high pressure, is actually at atmospheric pressure—since I am just above sea level. What is the explanation? (Wasn't the air inside the board also at 1 atm before I inflated it, when it was just lying on the ground? What's keeping the rubber taut when it's inflated?)

Comment: 15psi gauge or absolute? Likely gauge, which means it was inflated to 30psi absolute, or 15psi above ambient at sea level. Most inflation gauges read relative to ambient.

Comment: That would make sense then, thank you. What a relief, I thought I must be really off in my understanding of pressure somehow!

Comment: @JonCuster Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the purposes of inflating tires, rafts, basketballs, etc. the ambient (atmospheric) pressure is taken to be *zero*: a tire pressure gauge will read *zero* pressure when it is actually sensing *ambient* pressure, 15 PSI. The measured pressure in pounds per square inch is then called PSIG, where the "G" stands for "gauge"

For physics purposes, a *vacuum* is considered zero pressure and ambient is therefore 15 PSI. So a physics gauge will read 15 PSI *when it is not connected to anything*. This measurement is called PSIA ; the "A" stands for *absolute*.

Therefore 0 PSIG = 15 PSIA, and 15 PSIG = 30 PSIA.